# Laravel passport send dynamic token scopes in oauth/token API

Tags: laravel, user-permissions, user-roles, laravel-passport

I have user_master table, role_master table and a child table called user_roles which have references of user id and role id which indicates which user belongs to which role.

I have one more permission table which indicates which permissions belong to which roles.

For example:

---

user master table:

id           user_master     password

1            John                 some_md5

2            Jane                 some_md5

---

role_master table:

id           role_name

1           Administrator

2           Data entry operator

---

user_roles:

id           user_id          role_id

1             1                    1

2             2                    2

---

permissions:

id           permission_name           role_id

1           content.create                 1

2           content.create                 2

3           content.delete                    1

In [Laravel passport token scope doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#token-scopes), its mentioned that we can pass the token scopes in `AuthServiceProvider`. But in this case, the roles and permissions scope are dynamic so is it best practice to load them in `AuthServiceProvider` from database table?

And in `oauth/token` API, we are supposed to pass the scope. But as per this dynamic example, we can not pass * as scope because some roles have limited accessibility and some roles can access everything. So once we have user name and password sent as `POST` from web/mobile applications, then how we can pass the scope because before `oauth/token` triggers, we will not have user roles and scope information.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks!